# Why passing a concrete type to function solves the error?

Tags: haskell, types, syntax, polymorphism, typeclass

*p.s:* I wasn't sure how to name my question, fell free to let me know how I should have named it.

If not specifying the concrete type, I get this error, which is very clear and easy to solve:

> *Ambiguous type variable `a0` arising from a use of `fct`
>   prevents the constraint `(Read a0)` from being solved.
>   Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0` should be.*

I just need more explanation on why it worked? How `Read` will know what is the type to return:

```
fct :: (Show a, Read b) => a -> b
fct = read . show

main = do
  -- DOES NOT WORK: -- print (fct 4)   
  -- WORKS: -- print (fct 4 :: Int)
```

Comment: What is `fct` doing here?

Comment: That looks like it annotating the return, not the argument. It already knows what the argument type is since you're passing a literal. You're telling it that the call to that function will evaluate to an `Int`, so that means that `read` must return an `Int`.

Answer (score 6):

`(fct 4 :: Int)` means `(fct 4) :: Int`, not `fct (4 :: Int)`. The former specifies that the result of `fct` must be `Int`, hence `read` must be used to turn a string into an `Int`.

Instead, the literal `4` is left unconstrained. This triggers the so-called defaulting rules, which choose `Integer` for its type. Such defaulting, roughly, happens when a numeric literal is left ambiguous. Defaulting was introduced to let code like `print 4` work without annotations -- a small "special case" for programmers' convenience.

Concluding: `show` is called to turn `4 :: Integer` into the string `"4"`, which is then read back into `4 :: Int`.